# Magento orders : bad increment_id on imported customers

Tags: magento

It's my first time here, so i apologize in advance if i do some mistakes :)

I'm currently facing an extremely strange behaviour on a Magento 1.6.2.0 website.
After importing thousands accounts from a prestashop database, it seems that if an imported customer make a new order on magento, the increment_id of the order does not follow the last one stored in eav_entity_store, but a lower/unused increment_id.

Example :

Last increment_id available in database is : *100025008*
If a new customer finalize an order, its increment_id will be *100025009*.
BUT if an imported customer finalize an order, its increment_id will be a "random" number (i guess it's a number pick up from not used increment_id)

If, i re-save this imported account from magento backend, the next increment_id will be fine.

I dig deep into database customer_entity_*, customer_address_entity_* etc. to compare new vs.imported customer accounts & addresses, but even if i sync the data, the problem is not solved until i save account on backend. It's not an option because we've got more than 20k imported customers :)

I try to log the process of increment_id attribution in quotes but did not find relevant things until now.

Maybe someone here can give me the way to fix this stange behaviour ?

Thanks in advance for reading/helping !

Renaud

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly try using the Magento database repair tool.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/db-repair-tool

Be warned, however, that if you are not comfortable doing this kind of thing, the solution may not be for you. And, of course, backup everything prior to running this and/or set up a development environment to use for testing.